# How to make a link inside a .click function inside a loop for an array work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to, when the tr is clicked, open a new tab with an address, that is a Google Maps address with the variables from the code in between.

I have this HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <span class="place-address">A Street, 608, City</span>
    <a class="link-maps"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <span class="place-address">A Street, 998, City</span>
    <a class="link-maps"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <span class="place-address">A Street, 226, City</span>
    <a class="link-maps"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this JavaScript, in jQuery:

```
var addressesArray = [];
var linkMapsArray = [];

var placeAddress = $(".place-address").each(function() {

    var addresses = $(this).text();
    addressesArray.push(addresses);
});

var linkMaps = $(".link-maps").each(function() {

    var links = $(this);
    linkMapsArray.push(links);
});

var placesAddresses = addressesArray;

$(function() {

    getLocation();
});

function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(openMaps, showError);
    } else {

        alert("Your navigator doesn't support geolocation.");
    }
}

function openMaps(position) {

    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    for(j = 0; j < placesAddresses.length; j++) {

        var address = placesAddresses[j];
        linkMapsArray[j].closest("tr").click(function() {

            window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "/" + address + "/")
        });
    }
}

//omitted showError function
```

I don't want the link-maps to appear, that's why they are empty and with a `display: none` in the CSS.

The result of all of this is that, no matter which one of the tr's I click, it will always take me to the address of the last one. But when I put the following code instead of the click function, along with `display: block` in the CSS, it works, but only when clicking the link, but I want it to work when clicking the tr:

```
linkMapsArray[j].text(address);
linkMapsArray[j].attr("href", "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "/" + address + "/");
```

PS: I know that this last code doesn't open a new tab, but it is redirecting correctly.

Comment: How are you calling openMaps?  Where does the `position` parameter come from?

Comment: I edited the code to put the function from which I get the position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite follow what you're trying to do. This will log the text contained within the first child `<span class="place-address">...</span>` of a `<tr>` when the `<tr>` is clicked. From here, you'll need to construct a Google Maps link and call `window.open(...)` to open a new tab.

```js
(function(){
  // get all <tr> tags
  document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function (tr) {
    // listen for click events on each <tr>
    tr.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      // log the text of the .place-address span within the clicked <tr>
      console.log(tr.querySelector('.place-address').innerText);
      // TODO open a new tab here window.open(...)
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="place-address">A Street, 608, City</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="place-address">A Street, 998, City</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="place-address">A Street, 226, City</span>
      </td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a listener to each table row, consider using an event-delegation approach using `.on()`.

```js
(function() {
  getLocation();

  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleRowClicks, showError);
    } else {
      alert("Your navigator doesn't support geolocation.");
    }
  }

  function showError() {
    // omitted
  }

  function handleRowClicks(currentPosition) {
    $("#places").on("click", "tr", function() {
      openGoogleMaps(userPosition);
    });
  }

  function openGoogleMaps(currentPosition) {
    let address = $(this).find(".place-address").text();
    let latitude = currentPosition.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = currentPosition.coords.longitude;
    let url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "/" + address + "/";

    console.log(url);
    // window.open(url);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="places">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="place-address">A Street, 608, City</span>
      <a class="link-maps"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="place-address">A Street, 998, City</span>
      <a class="link-maps"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="place-address">A Street, 226, City</span>
      <a class="link-maps"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The latitude and longitude data that I'm using is the position of the user, it is just one for all the addresses.